# Split Sentences of a String

Tags: python, split

HI i am trying to split a text

```
For example
'C:/bye1.txt'
i would want 'C:/bye1.txt' only

'C:/bye1.txt C:/hello1.txt'
i would want C:/hello1.txt only

'C:/bye1.txt C:/hello1.txt C:/bye2 C:/bye3'
i would want C:/bye3 and so on.
```

Code i tried, Problem is it only print out Y.

```
x = "Hello i am boey"
Last = x[len(x)-1]
print Last
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this:

```
>>> x = 'C:/bye1.txt'
>>> x.split()[-1]
'C:/bye1.txt'
>>> y = 'C:/bye1.txt C:/hello1.txt'
>>> y.split()[-1]
'C:/hello1.txt'
>>> z = 'C:/bye1.txt C:/hello1.txt C:/bye2 C:/bye3'
>>> z.split()[-1]
'C:/bye3'
>>>
```

Basically, you split the strings using [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and then get the last item (that's what `[-1]` does).

Answer (score 1):

```
x = "Hello i am boey".split()
Last = x[len(x)-1]
print Last
```

Though more Pythonic:

```
x = "Hello i am boey".split()
print x[-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
>>> x = 'C:/bye1.txt C:/hello1.txt C:/bye2 C:/bye3'
>>> x.split()[-1]
'C:/bye3'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

`x[len()-1]` returns you the last character of the list (in this case a list of characters). It is the same as `x[-1]`

To get the output you want, do this:

```
x.split()[-1]
```

If your sentences are separated by other delimiters, you can specify the delimeter to split like so:

```
delimeter = ','
item = x.split(delimeter)[-1] # Split list according to delimeter and get last item
```

In addition, the "lstrip()", "rstrip()", and "strip()" functions might be useful for removing unnecessary characters from the end of your string. Look them up in the python documentations.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

```
'C:/bye1.txt C:/hello1.txt C:/bye2 C:/bye3'.split()[-1]
```

would give you `'C:/bye3'`.

#### Details:

The `split` method without any parameter assumes space to be the delimiter. In the example above, it returns the following list:

```
['C:/bye1.txt', 'C:/hello1.txt', 'C:/bye2', 'C:/bye3']
```

An index of `-1` specifies taking the first character in the reversed order (from the back).